# Control is getting be NULL mf

Tags: c++, null, mfc, controls, call

I have `CPrinterDlg` class which contains

```
 // CPrinterDlg.h    
 
public:
CEdit m_editRxFreq;
void print_SignalData(unsigned int freq, float wvlen);


// CPrinterDlg.cpp

void CPrinterDlg::print_SignalData(unsigned int freq, float wvlen)
{
   m_editRxFreq.SetWindowTextW(L"ddd");
}
```

In order to access that function I did in `MainFrm` like this:

```
public: 
CPrinterDlg m_PrinterDlg;
CPrinterDlg& getPrinterDlg() { return m_PrinterDlg; }
```

And from where I am calling `print_SignalData(...) is` CSMsg``` class

```
void CSockMsg::Send_SignalData(unsigned char* msg)
{
  //..

  CMainFrame* pMain = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();
  pMain->getPrinterDlg().print_SignalData(freq, wvlen);
}
```

When I call `print_SignalData(...)` from one of the CPrinter function directly, it's working well. But, When I try to call it from `CSMsg::Send_SignalData(unsigned char* msg)` it's giving me **Debug Assertion**(`...MFC\winocc.cpp Line: 242`) from this point:`m_editRxFreq.SetWindowTextW(L"ddd");`.
And I see that m_editRxFreq is `NULL`.

So, how do you think why `m_editRxFreq` is getting be NULL? and how can I solve this problem??

Comment: `CEdit` is a class, so `m_editRxFreq` can never be NULL, only pointers can be NULL. Unfortunately there's not enough information here to solve your problem. In particular there's nothing about how `m_editRxFreq` is given a value in the first place.

Comment: _"it's giving me an error"_: please [edit] and show the verbatim error message.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I editted that one, please take a look)

Comment: Now you should look closely to the error message and do what it suggests, that is click on the the "Retry" button which will open the winocc.cpp file at lines 242 which will reveal what actually was wrong. Probably the `m_editRxFreq.m_hWnd` window handle is NULL. probably because the CPrinterDlg dialog is no longer open.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  yes, ```m_editRxFreq.m_hWnd``` is NULL. so, if CPrinterDlg is no longer open, is there some way to reopen this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I was doing

```
public: 
CPrinterDlg m_PrinterDlg;
CPrinterDlg& getPrinterDlg() { return m_PrinterDlg; }
```

in `CMainFrm.h`,

and actually Creating and Showing that dlg

```
CPrinterDlg dlg;
dlg.Create(...);
dlg.ShowWindow(...);
```

was in `CxxView::OnInitialUpdate()`.

That's why when I called `pMain->getPrinterDlg().print_SignalData(freq, wvlen);` it was giving me NULL;

So in order to solve it,

I created CPrinterDlg `dlg.Create(...)` in `CMainFrm` class but not in `CxxxView` class.